# jquery: how to update input value using onchange?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a discount function for my order page where I have an issue that is , on my order page by default when `product quantity` is `1` then discounted rate show correctly in `Final textbox` but when I change the `Quantity, like 1 to 2,3,4,5..` then my code not works and the amount show without `discount rate`.
I try to fix this but I not understand where is mistake and how I fix that.

Below is my code which I am using please help and tell me how I make this correct.

Your help will be really appreciate.

Thank you!

```js
function getTotal(row = null) {
    if(row) {
      var disc = $('#dis_1').val();//
      var dec = (disc/100).toFixed(2);  //
      var total = Number($("#rate_value_"+row).val()) * Number($("#qty_"+row).val()) * dec;
      //total = total.toFixed(2);
      var rate = Number($("#rate_value_"+row))-total;
      total = total.toFixed(2);
      $("#amount_"+row).val(total);
      $("#amount_value_"+row).val(total);
      
      subAmount();

    } else {
      alert('no row !! please refresh the page');
    }
  }

//**---**/


  //*---*//
  
  // get the product information from the server
  function getProductData(row_id)
  {
    var product_id = $("#product_"+row_id).val();    
    if(product_id == "") {
      $("#rate_"+row_id).val("");
      $("#rate_value_"+row_id).val("");

      $("#qty_"+row_id).val("");           

      $("#amount_"+row_id).val("");
      $("#amount_value_"+row_id).val("");

    } else {
      $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'orders/getProductValueById',
        type: 'post',
        data: {product_id : product_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {
          // setting the rate value into the rate input field
          
          $("#rate_"+row_id).val(response.price); 
          $("#rate_value_"+row_id).val(response.price);

          $("#dis_"+row_id).val(response.discount);
          $("#dis_value_"+row_id).val(response.discount);
          
          $("#qty_"+row_id).val(1);
          $("#qty_value_"+row_id).val(1);

          //DISCOUNT      
        
          var disc = $('#dis_1').val();
          var dec = (disc/100).toFixed(2);   
          var total = Number(response.price) * dec;
          var rate = Number(response.price)-total;
          total = rate.toFixed(2);
          $("#amount_"+row_id).val(total);
          $("#amount_value_"+row_id).val(total);
          subAmount();
        } // /success
      }); // /ajax function to fetch the product data 
    }
  }
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty_1" class="form-control" required onkeyup="getTotal(1)" placeholder="Quantity"></td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Rate">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Discount" name="dis[]" id="dis_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Total Price" name="amount[]" id="amount_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
    </td>
```

> I am using my database to fetch the amount like product real rate, discounts.

Comment: sounds like onchange you need to redo the calculation

Comment: Your provided code is incomplete, but this looks pretty suspect: `onkeyup="getTotal(1)"`

Comment: @Johncartor It appears that you did not post the full JavaScript code so it is hard to tell what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

In your line of HTML

```
    <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty_1" class="form-control" required onkeyup="getTotal(1)" placeholder="Quantity"></td>
```

you are always calling getTotal with a value of 1, I think you want to instead get the value of the text box when the getTotal function is called and use that as your *row* value. In jquery you can get the value of the box by

```
row = $("#qty").val()
```

Comment: Instead of passing the row number in from your HTML as you do in the 2nd line of your HTML, you should get the value of the row from your js file by putting the row = $("#qty").val() as the first line of your getTotal function